# Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 aborted upgrade

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04. The output for `sudo do-release-upgrade` ended with:

```
 ubuntu-desktop
Exception during pm.DoInstall():  E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Could not install the upgrades 

The upgrade has aborted. Your system could be in an unusable state. A 
recovery will run now (dpkg --configure -a). 

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-desktop:
 ubuntu-desktop depends on gdm3; however:
  Package gdm3 is not installed.
 ubuntu-desktop depends on gnome-shell; however:
  Package gnome-shell is not installed.
 ubuntu-desktop depends on software-properties-gtk; however:
  Package software-properties-gtk is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-desktop (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of software-properties-common:
 gnupg (2.2.4-1ubuntu1) breaks software-properties-common (<= 0.96.24.3) and is installed.
  Version of software-properties-common to be configured is 0.96.20.10.

dpkg: error processing package software-properties-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ubuntu-desktop
 software-properties-common

Upgrade complete 

The upgrade has completed but there were errors during the upgrade 
process. 

To continue please press [ENTER]
```

The output for `sudo apt update` is:

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [118 kB]
Fetched 118 kB in 2s (49.3 kB/s)      
Reading package lists... Done
E: No priority (or zero) specified for pin
```

and `sudo dpkg --configure -a` gives:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-desktop:
 ubuntu-desktop depends on gdm3; however:
  Package gdm3 is not installed.
 ubuntu-desktop depends on gnome-shell; however:
  Package gnome-shell is not installed.
 ubuntu-desktop depends on software-properties-gtk; however:
  Package software-properties-gtk is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-desktop (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of software-properties-common:
 gnupg (2.2.4-1ubuntu1) breaks software-properties-common (<= 0.96.24.3) and is installed.
  Version of software-properties-common to be configured is 0.96.20.10.

dpkg: error processing package software-properties-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ubuntu-desktop
 software-properties-common
```

Finally, the output for `apt-cache policy`:

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
Pinned packages:
E: No priority (or zero) specified for pin
```

I haven't rebooted the computer. How do I ensure everything (or at least package management) is working?

Comment: What is the output of `grep "^deb\ " -r /etc/apt/ --include=*.list` ? Add to question.

Comment: And `ls /etc/apt/preferences.d/` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove "`E: No priority (or zero) specified for pin`" message you have to remove the Ubuntu Advantage (UA) ESM files by

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/ubuntu-esm-infra
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-esm-infra.list
```

as Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is supported release, so no UA ESM is really needed here.

Then check that you have correct lines in the `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Change lines to contain the following:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Then run `sudo apt-get update` again followed by:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get upgrade # rerun upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade # install newest dependencies
```

And  finally remove UA with

```
sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-advantage-tools --autoremove
```